# Why this json Symfony output outputs the headers

Tags: symfony, drupal-8

This is my first day to have fun with Symfony and drupal 8, so please excuse me if my question is very obvious.

**With drupal 7:**

```
drupal_json_output(array('products' => array_values($products)));
exit;
```

the json output is clean:

```
{"products":["item_1","item_2",....]}
```

**With drupal 8:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse; 
// some process
print new JsonResponse(array('products' => array_values($products)));
exit;
```

It outputs with the headers:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Wed, 18 Jul 2012 07:53:26 GMT

{"products":["item_1","item_2",....]}
```

How do you get rid of those headers?

I am stuck to read the reference [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!vendor!symfony!http-foundation!Symfony!Component!HttpFoundation!Tests!JsonResponseTest.php/8).

Any hint is very much appreciated.

Comment: print new JsonResp... is for debug. Use method `send()` for sending output

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will need to read more complete docs. Cross ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623962/looking-for-symfony2-book?rq=1

Comment: @swan You could edit my answer to improve it and write about `send()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get only the "content" of a response by calling `$response->getContent()`.

In your case you could do

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse; 
// some process
$response = new JsonResponse(array('products' => array_values($products)));
print $response->getContent();
exit;
```

However, be aware that this would be a bad practice because you would lose the response headers in the process, and wouldn't tell for example, what the content-type of you response is (in this case: "application/json") etc ...

I do not know how to do this properly with drupal, any tips is appreciated.