# Symfony 2.5 prints cache header

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I am using Symfony 2.5. I return my view template page from controller.

However, when I render the page, it displays raw cache as first part in `<body>` tag.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Thu, 26 Jun 2014 06:07:05 GMT  []
```

I googled and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836015/symfony-ajax-response-displays-cache-header) (which is similar as my problem) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536952/why-this-json-symfony-output-outputs-the-headers) (which is vaguely same).

So I tried all of the following one by one. But nothing worked.

```
return $this->render('MyBookBundle:Section:splash.html.php' , $this->data);
```

and

```
echo $this->renderView('MyBookBundle:Section:splash.html.php' , $this->data);
return new Response();
```

and

```
$displaypage =  $this->renderView('MyBookBundle:Section:splash.html.php' , $this->data);
return new Response( $displaypage );
```

and

```
$displaypage =  $this->render('MyBookBundle:Section:splash.html.php' , $this->data);
return new Response( $displaypage->getContent() );
```

My webpage is in its simplest possible stage.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Still none of those methods worked. Can someone please guide me in right direction ?

Comment: Is your web server apache2? If you look at source code (not using the debugguer, but by going into the page source), are those data written at the very top of the page or really after the `<body>` tag?

Comment: Yes. That's right. I am using Apache 2 and the data appears immediately after `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know if following the right answer, but it worked for me. Hope it helps some newbie like me out there.

In my controller, I was making some `forward` calls to other controllers to get required data.
In those controllers (the once which are dynamically called), I was returning a response object. This was causing the problem. However, as soon as I returned just plain string, the cache display problem disappeared.

Ideally, I would have to return response object from controller's `Action` methods. However, in this case, it worked without returning response object.

I am new to Symfony2, I tried to google a bit but couldn't find any difference or reason for this cause. If anyone can enlighten then it would be great.

p.s. I believe I should change those controllers, which are not serving page but only does background work, to services.